# Forward height/width information into classification model?

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification, computer-vision, object-detection

*Please forgive me if it's not the right StackExchange, but I didn't find any related to computer vision questions.*

**Problem:**
I have a pipeline for object detection and classification where I first classify some objects in "parent" class, then I use a classification model on those just detected objects to classify them with more precision. Here's a schema to get a better understanding:

[image]

Here `{star; round}` are my parents class, found by the detection model. Then 2 classifications models are used to find more precise classes. But in order to forward each cropped images, I need to resize them to a fixed size. And the problem comes here because when resizing I lost major information about the size of the object, thus I have a not really good classification.

**Things I tried without significant better results:**

- encode height and width in 3rd and 4th channel of image
- encode height and width in the last layer before fc in each classification model
- pad cropped image to a larger size

**Questions:**

- Is there something, a method or techniques I missed where I could use height and width info to get better results?
- Could I get information on height and width from the detection model? (I use efficentdet)
- Anything I did not think of?

Of course, the problem is way more complex than this one, I have +20 detections classes and +200 classes in total, really unbalanced. This is why I'm not for example just using a detection model for everything.